# access all elements in a netlogo table

Tags: netlogo

I have built a model where turtles traverse an environment and build a table (using the table extension) that represents the number of times they have visited each particular location, of which there are potentially several thousand (these are keyed on the 'who' of the location).

This works fairly effectively as it allows turtles that don't move around much to store smaller structures than those that travel a lot.

However, I would like to implement a procedure that once every so many cycles decrements these visit counts - such that every item in a turtle's table is decremented by some amount. I am struggling to find a way to access all the items in a table without specifying all the keys.

Does anyone know how this can be done easily? or are tables simply not designed in such a fashion?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok - so here goes - as is often the case, once you specify your problem you figure a solution to it.

This can be done by returning all the keys from the table then stepping through them using foreach and accessing each element one by one.

```
to decay

    let memory table:keys location-visits

    foreach memory
    [
        x -> let visits table:get location-visits x
        table:put location-visits x (visits - 1)
    ]

end
```

My real version also checks to make sure that visits never drops below zero.

At this stage, this seems relatively efficient - but I'd be happy if there were faster ways - thankfully i'm not running this code every cycle.

Hopefully this is of use to someone - I feel rather silly now.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is an open issue on the `table` extension proposing to add a `table:map` procedure that would do exactly what you need, here: https://github.com/NetLogo/Table-Extension/issues/6.

In that issue, Bryan Head proposes a NetLogo implementation of such a primitive:

```
to-report table-map [ tbl fn ]
  report table:from-list map [ entry ->
    list (first entry) (runresult fn last entry)
  ] table:to-list tbl
end
```

In your case, it would be used like this:

```
set location-visits table-map location-visits [ visits -> visits - 1 ]
```

This may or may not be faster than your own solution, but it might be worth trying. The main advantage is that if `table:map` ever became a reality, it would be a one-character change (from `-` to `:`) for your code to take advantage of it.